# Proving by Splitting the mod example

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Prove that, for all positive integers a, m, and n,

$(a)^m$+$(a+1)^n \equiv 1 + a(1 + (-1)^{m-1}) \pmod{a(a + 1)}$

I know using split the modulus is the first step to break the $a$ and $(a+1)$ but don't know how to actually prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Bring everything to the LHS:
$$a^m - a(-1)^{m-1} + (a+1)^n - (a+1) \equiv 0 \mod a(a+1)$$
Or regrouping:
$$a(a^{m-1} - (-1)^{m-1}) + (a+1)((a+1)^{n-1} - 1) \equiv 0 \mod a(a+1)$$
Can you figure it out from there?